# How can I check a Java file for errors, without producinv a .class file?

Tags: java, javac

Is there a way to have javac only check a Java file for errors, but without compiling it to a class file? I'm only interested in checking whether the file has syntax errors and so on. I don't want the compiled class file.

Comment: `javac MyClass.java && rm MyClass.class`?

Comment: I'm not sure javac can do this. Is producing the class file a problem?

Comment: Not a big deal, other than the waste of cpu and disk space. Is there a least a way to tell it to pipe the class file straight to /dev/null, so I don't have to do a separate `rm` command?

Comment: Btw, you could try another approach e.g. Eclipse JDT, the `JavaCompiler` class or some other syntax checker (depending on your needs you could also try to use ANTLR with a [Java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java)).

Comment: You try this  -> javac -Werror filename.java  but only problem is it will stop compilation if there are any error and warnings as well.